# "Undefined name" for value present in outer scope of where

Tags: scope, idris

I want to use a value defined in the outer scope of a where clause, like so

```
foo : Nat
foo = case Just 1 of
  Nothing => 0
  Just x => bar where
    bar : Nat
    bar = x
```

but I'm getting

```
Error: While processing right hand side of foo. While processing right hand side of foo,bar. Undefined name x. 

Foo.idr:30:11--30:12
    |
 30 |     bar = x
```

I don't understand this given what it says in [the docs](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html?highlight=where#where-clauses)

> Any names which are visible in the outer scope are also visible in the where clause (unless they have been redefined, such as xs here). A name which appears in the type will be in scope in the where clause.

Binding x to a new name on the RHS

```
foo : Nat
foo = case Just 1 of
  Nothing => 0
  Just x => let x' = x in bar where
    bar : Nat
    bar = x'
```

results in a similar error `Undefined name x'` for `bar = x'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be looking for `let` not `where`. Outer scope means arguments to `foo`.

Comment: hmmm ... in my actual code, `bar` is unary function and I'm returning that. I could do that with `let`, but it feels more natural to use `where` where I'm defining inner functions. I can expand my example if that would help

Comment: would outer scope include a `with` component?

Comment: @joel maybe. Try it and see. It should see anything defined in the LHS.